# Asignar un subdominio a servidor iis 8

Tags: iis, dns, dominio, cpanel, windows-server-2012

Estimados,
Tengo dos webs en un servidor iis 8 con windows server 2012. Ademas tengo un hosting web aparte (con CPanel), del cual saco un dns para una de las webs alojadas en mi IIS (web1.dominio.com).
Hace poco hice la segunda web que tengo en el servidor IIS y necesito asignarle otro dns proveniente de mi hosting web, algo asi como web2.dominio.com.

En el servidor IIS tengo separadas las dos webs por el puerto, es decir:

**Web1** -> 123.45.67.8:80
**Web2** -> 123.45.67.8:81

Como saben, no se puede establecer el puerto en las configuraciones del DNS en CPanel y requiero que la primera web se mantenga sin modificaciones ya que esta siendo utilizada actualmente.

¿Como puedo crear la redireccion correctamente, de modo que pueda acceder a la web2 con web2.dominio.com?

Quedo atento.

Answer (score 2):

Bueno, haciendo pruebas ya he podido solucionarlo y creo que publicar la respuesta le puede servir a otra persona.

Lo que hice fue colocar ambas webs en el puerto 80 modificando los enlaces haciendo click derecho en los sitios respectivos de mi IIS y seleccionando **"modificar enlaces"**. Ahí también realice la modificación de los host colocando como **nombre de host** "web1.dominio.com" y "web2.dominio.com" respectivamente.

Por ultimo, en CPanel asigne ambos dns a la **misma IP**, siendo IIS el responsable de identificar a que URL se quiere ingresar y redirigiendo a la web correspondiente.

Espero que a alguien le pueda ser útil esta informacion.